# Rounded textBox

Tags: textbox, libgdx

Is ShapeRenderer class has the ability to do this,I would like to create  boundaries for a custom object (such as a rectangle with rounded corners) and then fill it.And after that some text on that filled rounded box.

```
shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeType.Filled);
shapeRenderer.setColor(Color.RED);
//shapeRenderer.line(...);
shapeRenderer.curve(x1, y1, cx1, cy1, cx2, cy2, x2, y2, segments);
shapeRenderer.line(...);
shapeRenderer.curve(...);
shapeRenderer.line(...);
shapeRenderer.curve(...);
shapeRenderer.line(...);
shapeRenderer.curve(...);
shapeRenderer.setColor(Color.BLACK);
shapeRenderer.fill();
shapeRenderer.end();
```

Any suggestion to do it in libgdx.

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d.ui

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Lestat said, you can use [Scene2d](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d).

Whether you are using Scene2d or not, a NinePatch would probably be suitable if you want to draw a rounded rectangle that scales well (check [this link](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Ninepatches)).

If you want to be able to set the color of your image/control, you can use `NinePatch.setColor()`.

Here are two example scenarios regarding colors:

1. You will always have a black stroke/outline, and an arbitrary fill. In this case make the original image have black stroke/outline and white interior. When you 'tint' the image using `NinePatch.setColor()`, the stroke/outline will be unaffected and will remain black, while the interior (fill) will be the same as the color provide to the mentioned method.
2. You have arbitrary fill and arbitrary stroke. In this case you need 2 separate original images. First one would contain the 'fill' and would be completely white. Second one would contain the 'stroke' in white color and would be transparent inside. When drawing you would draw first the fill with its tint and then the stroke with its tint and that's all.

If for some reason you needed different corner curve radii, you would probably need separate images (or image pairs) for each radius to get the best result.

Comment: how to create this http://www.things4myhome.com/assets/images/goodwin/whiteboards/speech-bubble-whiteboard.jpg

Comment: @arv Do you need to have that shadow under or do you just need that shape with no outline?

Comment: That shape .... but i am able to change its hight and width of the rounded box.and the position of spike like shape also.

Comment: @arv Make the rounded rectangle shape the way I described in the answer. Use another image for that bottom spike and that is it. You will be able to change the size of the rounded rectangle and change the position of the spike because it is a separate image. You might want to make the spike larger than what is visible and render it before the rounded rectangle (so that the rounded rectangle is on top) to avoid any seam like artifacts between spike and rectangle.

Comment: then what about the border line of the rounded box that is coming at the position where i am adding the spike.

Comment: @arv If you need the border then you need to do it differently. Usually, it would be better to draw the inner part first and then the border, but to do what you want, you must draw the border of the rounded rect, then spike fill/border in the order you choose (or together), then the rounded rect fill. That's about it.